# ajax POST response is null

Tags: jquery, ajax

Trying to post data by clicking button, but in response getting null in  php script

here is html
   `<input type="button" id="btn" value="View Menu" style="padding: 5px 10px; background-color:green;"/>`

here is jquery

```
var action = 1;
$("input").on("click", sendData);
function sendData() {
if ( action == 1 ) {
    $("#btn").css("background", "red");
    var getData = 1;
        $.post({
          url: "drain.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {"getData" : getData}
        });
    action = 2;
} else {
    $("#btn").css("background", "green");
    var getData = 0;
        $.post({
          url: "drain.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {"getData" : getData}
        });
    action = 1;
    }
}
```

And here is the PHP Script where I'm trying to receive data (getData)

```
$rcvd_data=filter_input_array(INPUT_GET,[
    'data'=>FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    'dev_id'=>FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
]);

if($rcvd_data !== FALSE && !is_null($rcvd_data)) {
    $fp=fopen('drain.txt', 'a+');

    fwrite($fp, implode(', ', [
        0=>date('Y-m-d h:i:s A', time()),
        1=>$rcvd_data['data'],
        2=>$rcvd_data['dev_id']
    ]) . PHP_EOL);  
}

    $getData = $_POST['getData']; // here the posted data is recieved
    echo "@".$getData."#";
    die();
```

Comment: Please show us the form and the input field you are trying to post.

Comment: by clicking the button as stated above in html code, I want to trigger the ajax post

Comment: Modify your question and add the elements I asked for please. You have only provide a small piece of your HTML.

Comment: As @Dave says, you have not shown us everything.  You say `getting null in php script` - so show us the PHP script. If you want to check if your AJAX is firing at all, use your browser's dev tools, watch the network tab to see if the POST happens, and inspect it to see what data is POSTed.

Comment: Added the PHP script @Dave

Comment: $rcvd_data is not responsible for receiving data posted by ajax, $getData @Phil

Comment: $getData = $_POST['getData']; is not inside if statement @Phil

Comment: sorry, my mistake, typing error. Edited @Phil

Comment: So how are you verifying this problem? Your AJAX calls don't do anything with the response. If you look in your browser's _Network_ console, I suspect you'll see either `@1#` or `@0#` in the response which means everything is working as expected

Comment: everything seems fine as data is being posted but PHP script is not receiving the data as expected and giving NULL

Comment: How do you know? **How are you verifying the problem?**